# Get geo-locations from cities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, geolocation, ef-code-first

I am trying to display a list of closest restaurants of a given city within a radius. In order to do this, I'll have to convert the city to a longitude/latitude.

When the user fills in his/her restaurant information, he/she will fill in the address. Based on that address i need to get a longitude/latitude and save that to the database.

I don't need to point this on a map. I'll be just displaying a list of all closest restaurants within the given radius to the user.

How can I do this with `ASP.NET-MVC4`?
Also, this project is based on `Code First`. And for address I have `DbGeography` as datatype set.

The project is kind of based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859721) tutorial

**Edit**
To avoid anyone else telling me this is not possible with ASP.NET on it's own, I am aware of that. an example with Google maps / .NET wrapper would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps/) .NET wrapper which fulfills my need.

Answer (score 0):

This query itself is typically done in the database back-end because the program is the consumer of the data not the keeper of the data. You will have a table of restaurants, possibly for many cities, each restaurant having a latitude and longitude. You create a geospatial index on the table, which performs a tesselation for performance; you configure the tesselation parameters. You must determine the latitude/longitude of your restaurant-seeker's location. Your command object would feed that data to a stored procedure, along with the desired radius. The stored procedure would return an enumerable set of rows to your client program.

Comment: Hi, the problem now is more like how to get the latitude/longitude. I can't ask the form filler of the restaurant to enter these points in.

Comment: There is no way for ASP.NET to do that on its own. The user would have to provide a street address or intersection whose coordinates could be looked up using a web service; or a program running on the user's smart device (if applicable) might get the location from the device and pass it to the website. Same goes for restaurant owner. There are companies who will geocode a set of addresses for a fee. Using "free" sites has certain restrictions/limitations.

Comment: I was hoping for an example with google maps on how to get the geo locations? AFAIK, that should be possible?

Comment: Search for "consume webservice from ASP.NET MVC" or ditto "consume google webservice from mvc".